# How to transfer conversation from Bot to human agents?

Tags: bots

I have MS BOT client which the user will interact with. The Bot will use LUIS models for NLP. For any queries tagged under None, we should involve a human agent immediately. What is the best way to transfer the conversation from Bot client to human agent?

Answer (score 1):

I think, none intent is not the right place to divert chat to human assistant. You should use text analytics to find the sentiment of user's reply and if it scores negative then you should redirect the chat to human assistant.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Bot it provides a setting to transfer Bot-to-Human if needed or the bot is unable to understand. Here are the [steps to do on the Microsoft platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/handoff#:%7E:text=To%20use%20this%20feature%20activate,chat%20support%20from%20live%20agents.).

This changes depending on the Chatbot platform, for example, in Dialogflow JSON need to be used. In that JSON code, you can mention the [human agent Id](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/web-conversation-assignment#bot-to-human-handoff) and set like the ["Talk to Human" button](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-setup#how-to-set-up-the-talk-to-human-option) and transfer.